# Search Console Impressions Issue

Tags: google-search-console, google-analytics-4

We are currently on Google Analytics 4 and since we have updated our end to the new tracking code, we seem to have false data on Search Console impressions graph - see attached. [search console graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HOBr.png)

You can see at the point we updated the code, the data lost all trends (no longer down at weekends etc)

Got any ideas on what the issue could be?

Thanks, Brad

Comment: See if you can narrow down what is causing the impressions. e.g. is it a specific country, query term, device, page?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's not a programming question. I'd suggest looking at [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) for an answer.